# Escaping special character in Mongodb regex

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to match

```
"Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; U; Android 4.0.4; fr-ca; GT-S7560M Build/IMM76I) AppleWebKit/534.30 (KHTML, like Gecko)"
```

with

```
"Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; U; Android 4.0.4; fr-ca; GT-S7560M Build/IMM76I) AppleWebKit/534.30 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Mobile Safari/534.30"
```

I am using the following query

```
function regexEscape(string){
return string.replace(/[.*+?^${}()|[\]\\]/g, "\\$&");
}
var ua = regexEscape(user_string)
db.collection.find({ua:{$regex:'*.'.concat(ua,'.*'),$options:'si'}).count()
```

But the result is 0.

Can you guys tell me where I am going wrong?

Comment: I think you forgot the quotes, [`[.*+?^${}()|"'[\]\\]`](https://regex101.com/r/tL7tW8/1)

Comment: I didnt wrote that function I copied it from mozilla developer pagehttps://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions

Comment: I tried the above regex but it is not appending \ to the dots inside the parenthesis

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of effort I found the mistake,

```
db.collection.find({ua:{$regex:us.concat(".*"),$options:'si'}}).count()
```